# JavaScript Filling Default value back into text field on blur

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. I want the text to be filled by the default value when user lefts it blank here is my code. Please help me to tackle this error.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script lang='javascript'>
function makeBlank(obj,defMsg){
    if(obj.value==defMsg){
        obj.value="";
    }
}
function fillDefValue(obj,defMsg){
    if(obj.value==""){
        obj.value=defMsg;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input style="width:190px" onblur="fillDefValue(this,'User Name')" onfocus="makeBlank(this,'User Name')" value="Name" name="fromname" id="fromname" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code has one error i am correcting it

Comment: This code behaves as intended to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a minor error. The functions which make the text field blank or filled with default value have an if statement which checks the condition `if(obj.value==defMsg)` which is `defMsg='User Name'`. But in the text field you are assigning `value = "Name"` so the if condition never become true. Thats why your code is not working. You should either use `<input .... value="User Name" ......>` or you can call the both functions as `<input ...onblur="fillDefValue(this,'Name')" onfocus="makeBlank(this,'Name')" vlaue="Name"....>`. Doing any of these two changes the code will work fine. Here is your code with the first change  I mentioned:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script lang='javascript'>
function makeBlank(obj,defMsg){

    if(obj.value==defMsg){
        obj.value="";
    }
}
function fillDefValue(obj,defMsg){
    if(obj.value==""){
        obj.value=defMsg;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input style="width:190px" onblur="fillDefValue(this,'User Name')" onfocus="makeBlank(this,'User Name')" value="User Name" name="fromname" id="fromname" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to pass the default value to the functions, it's integral part of the textbox element itself:

```
function makeBlank(obj) {
    if(obj.value === obj.defaultValue){
        obj.value = "";
    }
}

function fillDefValue(obj) {
    if(obj.value == "") {
        obj.value = obj.defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Then pass only the element:

```
onblur="fillDefValue(this);" onfocus="makeBlank(this);"
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/m3cXV/) - it works on all major browsers, probably all browsers.

Comment: Thanks, just happened to know `defaultValue` - was surprised how simple it is when first bumping into it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably looking for the `placeholder` HTML attribute.

```
<input placeholder="e.g. username42">
```

You only need JavaScript as a fallback for older browsers. [This jQuery plugin will take care of it for you.](http://mths.be/placeholder) Here’s a demo: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder